# Is it possible to run a piece of code with extra privilege using JSOM in sharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, jsom

I have tried to find if it is possible but I did not find anything yet.
So, I just wanted to confirm here, if it is possible.

Comment: Not possible...

Comment: You can if you make a SharePoint hosted app, then you can use App permissions. Same is true for Workflows, they also use app permissions, but then you don't need to add an actual app file

Comment: If you need elevated privilege while write custom solution in JSOM then reconsider your architecture. JSOM was never meant for impersonation. Try to abstract out the functionality that requires impersonation and run it separately OR redesign the app as provider hosted app.

Answer (score 3):

No,It is not possible.We cannot have code with extra privilege in JSOM. Please refer below links.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/ef752641-63e9-400b-a7e7-f7d74d7ee533/run-csom-javascript-code-with-elevated-privileges

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028970/elevated-privileges-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Impersonation is not possible from Client Side JavaScript. 
I have also tried all possible solutions but no luck..